# starting on a new project(C# /ASP.NET) , need some guidelines on the framework and infra for the same

Tags: asp.net, wcf, entity-framework, c#-4.0, odata

so i am going to start on a website which is going to have

- Main Website
- Mobile Version
- Android App
- iPhone App
- WP7 App

going to start on the website first using .Net Framework 4 , for database  will be using the EF4. The website is expected to create lots of traffic.

i want to take advice on how to approach the development , currently evaluating following 2 options

1) Main Website and Mobile website versions talk directly to database and the mobile apps are built upon WCF / Odata .

2nd Option

First build up the WCF /OData webservices and then develop all Main Website / Mobile Website and apps using the data services ( will this make the website slow , assuming all will Database on one box and website + services on the other box)

please pour in your views on both options.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would choose the second option. Have a look at

- [Web Service Software Factory](http://servicefactory.codeplex.com/) that will help  you build web services correctly, and develop good practices.
- [ASP.NET MVC](http://www.asp.net/mvc) i recommend to use it for building web site, and your web services will serve as Model for site.

I would also put wcf services on the same server as database.

Regards,
 Sergiu.

Comment: Thanks Mate.. i am already starting with Web Service Software Factory!!